# C++ copy constructor error: Assignment of member 'Fraction::numerator' in read-only object

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

**My Header file:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Fraction
{
private:
    double numerator;
    double denominator;
public:
    Fraction();
    ~Fraction();
    Fraction(const Fraction& c);
    Fraction(double,double);
    //setter
    void setNumerator(double newnumerator);
    void setDenominator(double newdenominator);
    //getter
    double getNumerator();
    double getDenominator();

    //friend overlaoding operators

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Fraction f);

};
```

**My CPP file:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Fraction.h"

using namespace std;

Fraction::Fraction()
{
    cout<<"Empty constructor called"<<endl;
}

Fraction::~Fraction()
{
    cout<<"Deconstructor called"<<endl;
}

Fraction::Fraction(const Fraction& c)
{
    c.numerator = numerator;
    c.denominator = denominator;
}

Fraction::Fraction(double newnumerator, double newdenominator)
{
    numerator = newnumerator;
    denominator = newdenominator;
}

void Fraction::setNumerator(double newnumerator)
{
    numerator = newnumerator;
}

void Fraction::setDenominator(double newdenominator)
{
    denominator = newdenominator;
}

double Fraction::getNumerator()
{
    return numerator;
}

double Fraction::getDenominator()
{
    return denominator;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Fraction f)
{
     os<<f.numerator<<"/"<<f.denominator<<endl;
     return os;
}
```

**My testcpp.file:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Fraction.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Fraction f1;

    cout<<f1;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code I get bellow `error` message:

> Fraction.cpp: In copy constructor ‘Fraction::Fraction(const Fraction&)’:
>   Fraction.cpp:20:17: error: assignment of member ‘Fraction::numerator’ in   read-only object
>            `c.numerator = numerator;`
>
> Fraction.cpp:21:19: error: assignment of member ‘Fraction::denominator’ in  read-only object
>            `c.denominator = denominator;`

**PS:** Once I left out the copy copy constructor and tried if the rest really works, but I get the same `error` message for the *overloading operator*(`cin >>`).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Most of your code is irrelevant. You should post an [mcve].

Comment: Your`>>` operator should not take a const parameter, as it changes it (which is what the compiler is telling you).

Comment: I rolled this back, because your edits had completely changed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get rid of the const and put a ref. `&symbol` next to Fraction. why? to make changes on the object ?

```
friend istream& operator>>(istream &is, Fraction &f);

istream& operator>>(istream &is, Fraction &)
{

    cout<<"Enter numerator"<<endl;
    is>>f.numerator;
    cout<<"Enter denominator"<<endl;
    is>>f.denominator;

    return is;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your copy constructor is backwards.  You're supposed to copy FROM the parameterized instance to the `this` instance.

```
Fraction::Fraction(const Fraction& c)
{
    numerator = c.numerator;
    denominator = c.denominator;
}
```

Comment: It'd be better to use the ctor initializer list (or even `= default` in this case)

Comment: And even better to let the compiler do this for you.

Comment: I edited the question gents, could you check on the this one

Comment: @mathquestion you have a similar problem in another function... pay attention to the error messages, they tell you exactly where the problem is